# IE6 positioning issue - missing placed button image

Tags: css, positioning, internet-explorer-6

I have created a page with a "back" button at the bottom right. It looks well positioned in Firefox and more modern browsers however in Internet Explorer 6 the "back" button is missing.

http://www.aetnamarketingcommunications.com/DentalQuiz/QuizTestPage.html

I have tried adding z-index property to this absolute positioned image button without success...what could be the issue?
Thanks, Attila

Comment: I would not worry about IE 6, unless you have a critical audience segment that still depends on it.  From a MS standpoint however, IE 6 is officially dead.

Comment: As supported by Microsoft, http://www.ie6countdown.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this bug, try clearing your absolutely positioned element by adding `clear: both` to the anchor styling. It's a bug in IE6, and has nothing to do with floats.

IE6 is below 1% usage, not sure why you want to support it.

**Special Note About Z-Index (IE):** If you're using `z-index` in IE6-IE8, it should be noted that the stacking order in IE gets reset whenever you apply `position: absolute`, so the `z-index` is not relative to any of its parent containers.

Comment: Unfortunately, we still use IE6 internally at the company and although we are migrating to IE8 some internal reviewers will still visit the page using IE6 so I need to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't test for ie6 anymore but I would try *zoom:1 ing everything like so

```
* {
    *zoom: 1;
   }
```

and narrow it down from there..